# Will my debian testing become stable version, after new stable version released?

Tags: debian, package-management, version

Currently, Debian testing codename is `buster`, and next-stable will be `buster`.

I have installed Debian testing to keep packages up-to-date. My question is: Will my Debian become the `stable` release of Debian after `buster` is released as stable? If the answer is yes: I want to keep my Debian to testing version and keep packages up-to-date, What should I do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your `/etc/apt/sources.list` file references `buster` then it will stay on `buster` from `testing` through `stable` and then `old-stable`.

If you have referenced `testing` then it will stay on `testing` regardless of the current testing version.

You can see more details on the [Debian Wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/SourcesList), which includes a suggested `sources.list` file. I've taken that and tweaked it to reference `testing` as mentioned in your question:

```
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian testing main contrib non-free
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian testing main contrib non-free

deb http://deb.debian.org/debian-security/ testing/updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian-security/ testing/updates main contrib non-free

deb http://deb.debian.org/debian testing-updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian testing-updates main contrib non-free
```

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what name for the distribution you are using.

Check you `/etc/apt/sources.list` file. If it contains lines like:

```
deb http://ftp.nl.debian.org/debian/ buster main
```

then your system will stay with `buster`, even when it is released as a stable version.

If instead you have lines like:

```
deb http://ftp.nl.debian.org/debian/ testing main
```

then your system will remain with `testing`. be prepare for a whole lot of updates at the moment that `buster` is released, as before an official release the version undergoes a freeze period to iron out the last critical problems; however the next `testing` version will contain all changes made during the freeze.