# How to stay on debian Bullseye when it will become "stable"

Tags: debian, system-installation

I wanted to install debian on my new computer but i just realized that debian 10 was about to end and to be replaced by 11 as the new stable version.

So I chose to install debian testing in anticipation of that.
I don't know if it is the best option, I just thought that when it will be released I would already have it on my computer and would have nothing to do.

But now I am wondering if the stable debian 11 would be the same than the testing one.
And when it will become stable, maybe my computer will go to debian 12 as testing, since it has the debian "testing" as repositories.

So I don't really know what to do. Do I need to uninstall, install debian 10 and upgrade when release ? Or can I use my testing version and go on stable when release ?

Thank you for reading this ! Sorry if I am not really clear in my explanations. I am not a native english speaker neither a "techie guy".

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Will my debian testing become stable version, after new stable version released?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/485677)

Comment: Current 11 is "Debian 11 bullseye **rc2**", and in my install of rc2  the sources list has `deb http://deb.debian.org/debian/ bullseye main` , etc. etc. **bullseye** , i.e. nothing to change in the future.